# Twitter: streaming API, make a connection between multiple retweets

Tags: c#, javascript, twitter

I've looked at the API docs for the Twitter Streaming API https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis and looked at some similar questions on here, but they either don't address my specific problem or they relate to older versions of the API.

**Q: Is there an ID field, or similar property, that can allow me to make the connection between a retweet and its original source tweet?**

I understand there are some properties on each tweet, but they don't seem to give me the fullest picture:

- `retweeted`: should always be false for tweets that are streamed? As they won't have time to be retweeted?
- `retweet_count`: again, should always be 0 for newly harvested tweets?
- `retweet_status.retweet_count`: this seems the most useful so far, gives me the total running retweet count for a single retweet, but with the streaming I will still get duplicate tweets, is there some kind of source_tweet_id that I can use to determine duplicates?

Probably the way I would do it at the moment would be to look at the message strings for matches.

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you receive a retweet object, it should contain a property named retweeted_status that contains the ID of the tweet that's being retweeted. Look at the response from the example request for the retweets API: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/retweets/%3Aid

Comment: Excellent! It doesn't seem to catch the 'quote retweets' though, but a good start.